# What is the strategy of cleaning cache in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: http, google-chrome, firefox, caching, browser

I would like to ask you what is the strategy of cleaning cache in Chrome/Firefox, i.e. related to resources on the web like a images, css or javascript.

How does it works? For example, If I came on the example.com, the browser usually loads all css, image and javascript files. AFter next request on the page, the browser doesn't load each of the resources. If I didn't a hard refresh, how long it takes to the browser to reload the all resources automatically?

Thank you very much for your answers.